# Converting a template file in Microsoft Word docx file to LaTex file

Tags: pandoc, conversion, word-to-latex

I tried to use pandoc to convert a docx file, which is [Verra](https://verra.org/programs/verified-carbon-standard/vcs-program-details/#rules-and-requirements)'s template for project description (can be downloaded from [here](https://verra.org/documents/vcs-project-description-template-v4-3/)), using the following command line:

```
pandoc --reference-doc=custom-reference.docx -s VCS-Project-Description-Template-v4.3.docx -o VCS-Project-Description-Template-v4.3.tex
```

I used a reference file I have edited to match the above template (can be downloaded from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1byo_yguDKk6l4CDtedrGbNsGndOWZZKT/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102951044805096382597&rtpof=true&sd=true)), but for some reason it didn't use the file and the resulted tex file was not formated according to the reference file.
Someone has experience with such conversion using pandoc?

Comment: The docx template is only used when you generate a docx document. If you want to produce a latex file, you have to use a latex template. You can print the default latex template with `pandoc -D latex`. How templates for is well documented on pandoc's website: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates